# Word for difference between "in" and "into"

Tags: terminology, cases, prepositions

I was wondering whether there are words for the two types of prepositions, or a word for the distinction between them. I understand that the difference between them is that one is a "static" preposition, while the other describes motion towards the position. I've noticed there are also other such pairs, like "on" and "onto". Also, such distinctions don't exist in all languages, though it is not exclusive to English either.

Comment: There is plenty if you Google *preposition of movement*.  That’s not exactly a word for the distinction though.

Comment: In German and Slavic languages it’s one preposition but distinguished by case, they’re called *Wechselpräpositionen*.

Comment: Some useful articles on the semantic analysis of prepositions here - https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Semantic-Analysis-of-the-Preposition-Through-Yue-Cao/d0ae66134ed69569927ccad310a6286ed530cafa https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-lexical-semantic-analysis-of-the-English-at%2C-on-Almuoseb/e6b378d14e8f872e31f8e940d3790437b533a7cf In Swedish there’s *här* and *hit*, locational pronouns for “here” vs. “here-towards” - “Do you enjoy living *here*?” vs. “How did you get *to here*?” The question could be approached by beginning from a broad semantic analysis of prepositions.

Comment: "into" doesn't always imply motion.    See "The wire extends into the box."

Comment: I would still consider that "motion", as you are describing something that was outside but now inside (in this case. it's just that it's also still outside).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any standard terminology for this. If you called them *directional* versus *positional* prepositions, I imagine you would be easily understood. (Similarly for prepositions of *movement* versus prepositions of *location*.)

Comment: I'd add "locative" before "prepositions", just to  make sure "directional" and "positional" didn't generalize to other prepositions. AFAIK, that's the only way linguists use the terms, but we're not talking to linguists here. Someone may have just discovered the accusative/ablative group of Latin prepositions, for example. Including _in_.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is expressed by grammatical cases in some languages (e.g., Finnish), and [Lists of Grammatical Cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases) distinguish Location, Motion-to, and Motion-from. The most generic terms I can take from there are locative (Location), allative (Motion-to), and ablative (Motion-from).

Comment: So could I potentially use the terms for prepositions? For example, could I say, a *locative preposition*?

Comment: Yes, at least you will be understood when you use that.